# can anyone help with getting the Z Location data from the Music empty object into the radius value? /Sverchock

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes, geometry, mathematics, audio

[image]can anyone help with getting the Z Location data from the Music empty object into the radius value? Sverchok some help would be great!

Comment: can you please explain a bit more what you want to achieve? i understood - and i cannot really believe that i understood this right - that you want to make a radius from the z location? as far as i can see you already plugged it in there. So what is the problem?

Comment: its pretty much what this guy is doing here at 1:06:00 but with sverchok https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7EGSCo1YBI&t=2506s

Comment: i don't know whether you want to rebuild what he did in geometry nodes - but you are using sverchok. He uses geometry nodes for z location in that minute...

Comment: yea exactly what he is doing but with sverchok nodes... im just not clued up with sverchok nopes to the point where i can extrapolate the z location data

Comment: i would love a discord call if you have any ideas on who to solve this problem.  KILL NIKO#7384     is my username

Comment: if you share your blend file - i will try - but i have not soooo much Sverchok-experience - i am still learning